# Problem with XElement and XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, xelement, xslcompiledtransform

I'm having some trouble using a combination of `XElement` and `XslCompiledTransform`. I've put the sample code I'm using below. If I get my input XML using the `GetXmlDocumentXml()` method, it works fine. If I use the `GetXElementXml()` method instead, I get an `InvalidOperationException` when calling the `Transform` method of `XslComiledTransform`:

*Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment*.

The `CreateNavigator` method on both `XElement` and `XmlDocument` returns an `XPathNavigator`. What extra stuff is `XmlDocument` doing so this all works, and how can I do the same with `XElement`? Am I just doing something insane?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XslCompiledTransform stylesheet = GetStylesheet(); // not shown for brevity
    IXPathNavigable input = this.GetXElementXml();
    using (MemoryStream ms = this.TransformXml(input, stylesheet))
    {
        XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(ms);
        xr.MoveToContent();
    }
}

private MemoryStream TransformXml(
    IXPathNavigable xml,
    XslCompiledTransform stylesheet)
{
    MemoryStream transformed = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(transformed);
    stylesheet.Transform(xml, null, writer);

    transformed.Position = 0;
    return transformed;
}

private IXPathNavigable GetXElementXml()
{
    var xml = new XElement("x", new XElement("y", "sds"));
    return xml.CreateNavigator();
}

private IXPathNavigable GetXmlDocumentXml()
{
    var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml("<x><y>sds</y></x>");
    return xml.CreateNavigator();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that was easy. The solution was to wrap the `XElement` in an `XDocument` object. Problem solved!